# Dollar symbol inside lstlisting block turns on font-latex-math-face

Tags: auctex, latex, font-lock

I am using `lstlisting` to add `shell` code into my tex document. The `shell` code contains special character, `$`. Emacs assumes it as a Math mode mark & all characters that come after dollar symbol are shown in math-mode and latex keywords are n't highlighted in their normal bright green color. It looks like this,
[image]

I use AUCTeX.

Comment: Do you have file parsing enabled?  In that case you don't have to manually add `lstlisting` to `LaTeX-verbatim-environments` manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add "lstlisting" to `LaTeX-verbatim-environments` (using `M-x customize-variable`) and reopen your file.

courtesy: [s.overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802450/emacs-how-to-render-lslisting-as-verbatim)